# Scraping G2 using XPath in Python - "Pardon Our Interruption" response

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to get the Title of the page in G2 Crowd using Xpath and it seems that G2 doesn't allow to do it, as I get "Pardon Our Interruption". The code is a few lines and works with other sites, how this can be fixed?

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

resp = session.get("https://www.g2.com/categories/ipaas")

sites = resp.html.xpath("//title/text()")

print(sites)
```

I am a newbie in this, please assist how to scrape G2. Thanks.

Comment: Can't replicate the problem; I get `['Best iPaaS Software 2020: Compare Reviews on 170+ Software | G2']`.

Comment: This message appears in case you run the code several times. It seems that they block the access in case of several requests. Can this be somehow avoided?

Comment: Usually what you do is set a timer in your code and then run it only every x seconds or minutes, depending on how strict the page is.